# Is it possible to map an object type into a union

Tags: typescript

If I have an object type like the following

```
type Foo = {
  a: ValueA
  b: ValueB
}
```

Is it possible to create a generic mapped type that is a union of its key/value pair, like this?

```
type EntriesOf<Foo> = { key: 'a'; value: ValueA } | { key: 'b'; value: ValueB }
```

The best I can do is

```
type EntriesOf<Type> = { key: keyof Type; value: Type[keyof Type] }
```

But it results in

```
{ key: 'a' | 'b'; value: ValueA | ValueB }
```

Answer (score 0):

Found an answer

```
type ValuesOf<T> = T[keyof T]
type EntriesOf<T> = ValuesOf<{ [K in keyof T]: { key: K; value: T[K] } }>
```